# looping from long array is slow in ejs node js template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance

I am getting data from MongoDB and looping from it in ejs. and it is long data. it is an array of more than 28k objects because of that it's slow to load is there any way I can load all of the data without having to compromise performance?

I was trying to load data from MongoDB in ejs temp and print HTML  select options it is printing but it is slow

Comment: A dropdown with 28k elements probably isn't going to work on most computers and most browsers. You likely need to use something more like a typeahead solution that can filter the results before showing them.

Comment: Thank you it worked. instead of multi-select I used [amsifySuggestags](https://github.com/amsify42/jquery.amsify.suggestags)  and combined it with  typeahead solution using [autoComplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin with ajax